# How to know which thread is affected by notify() or notifyAll() - Java

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

Is there a way to *know* which Active Entity thread(s) is/are being affected by a `notify()` or `notifyAll()` which are called from inside of a Passive Entity Mutex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to know from the thread that makes the call to `notify()` *which* threads are woken up.

Also, there is no way to know from the woken up thread *which* thread woke them up.

It's just the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know this information, you can create a data structure which records this information.  However, you rarely need to know this so it doesn't do this for you automatically.